# Time difference issue of container and host

Tags: linux, time, containers, virtual-machine

I am running container in a Linux VM, the "date" command on VM gives the right time back, while in containers, "date" returns the same result as date on VM. What is different is that when I touch a file in container, and then ls -l this file, the time created is not the same as date in container returned. I tried the same steps on a Centos VM using docker, the date and container file time is the same. Below are the details, could anyone tells me what is the difference?

In VM:
date returns: Fri Jan 10 15:55:37 UTC 2020 
In Container:
date returns: Fri Jan 10 15:55:40 UTC 2020
then "touch aaaa" and ls -l aaaa returns: Jan 10 08:03 aaaa

The issue is date in container should returns the Jan 10 08:03, not the VM time.
Is there anything I missed while running a container?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but do check their help before posting.